# How to read a specific amount of lines from a file in C

Tags: c, file, output

My question is that I am trying to read only a certain amount of files given n files.

For example, I have the two files with the following content inside then

> test1:
>
> A cat ran off
>
> Apple
>
> test2:
>
> The boy went home
>
> Apples are red

I want the output to be

> test1: A cat ran off

Not

> test1: A cat ran off
>
> test2: Apples are red

This is the code that I have written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
 {
   extern int searcher(char * name, char*search,int amount);
   while(argc != 0){
   if(argv[argc] !=NULL)
     if(searcher(argv[argc],"a",1)) break;
     argc-- ;
   }
}

int searcher(char * name, char*search,int amount){

FILE *file = fopen (name, "r" );
int count = 0;

if (file != NULL) {
  char line [1000];
while(fgets(line,sizeof line,file)!= NULL && count != amount)
 {
  if(strstr(line,search) !=NULL){
    count++;
    if(count == amount){
      return(count);
    }
    printf("%s:%s\n", line,name);
  }
}

fclose(file);
}else {
    perror(name); //print the error message on stderr.
  }
 return(0);
}
```

Comment: Remember `fgets` reads a line at a time, you can easily set a counter and do `while (count < x && fgets (.....)) {...}`

Comment: Can you show me what you mean? Please add edit to code above.

Comment: Sure, but before I give an example, how many lines do you want to read from each file?, or are you searching within each file for a term. It looks like you are attempting a search (which is fine), but that is separate and apart from strictly reading `X` number of lines from a file. Do you need to do both?

Comment: What I am trying to do is. Read n lines of a file, search that file for a particular string, and stop. Currently, what is happening is both files are being read. Depending on the amount of lines in the file I want to go through all those, if nothing is found in those open the other files and go through those.

Comment: Please update your question and be specific about *files* and *lines*. At the moment, the title is out of line with what's written on the first line of the question. Also any clarification of the question needs to be in the question itself, not in the comments.

Comment: The issue I see is your `break` occurs in `searcher` which is doing nothing to stop the loop in `main`. Make `searcher` type `int` and return `count` and then in `main`, you can do `if (searcher(argv[argc],"a",1)) break;`

Comment: I made some changes in the code above. are they correct?

Comment: *Don't correct the code in the question!* Anyone reading it later will wonder what all the fuss was about.

Comment: @Kusalananda: The change was made before an answer was available. Due to the short time, it is in dubio pro reo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comments, and noting you will need to remove the trailing `newline` included by `fgets`, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXC = 1000 };

int searcher (char *name, char *search, int amount);
void rmlf (char *s);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        if (searcher (argv[i], "a", 1))
            break;

    return 0;
}

int searcher (char *name, char *search, int amount)
{
    FILE *file = fopen (name, "r");
    int count = 0;

    if (!file) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", name);
        return 0;
    }

    char line[MAXC] = "";
    while (count < amount && fgets (line, MAXC, file)) {
        rmlf (line);                    /* strip trailing \n from line */
        if (strstr (line, search)) {
            count++;
            printf ("%s: %s\n", name, line);
        }
    }

    fclose (file);
    return count == amount ? count : 0;
}

/** stip trailing newlines and carraige returns by overwriting with
 *  null-terminating char. str is modified in place.
 */
void rmlf (char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) return;
    for (; *s && *s != '\n'; s++) {}
    *s = 0;
}
```

**Example Input Files**

```
$ cat test1
A cat ran off
Apple

$ cat test2
The boy went home
Apples are red
```

**Example Use/Output**

You understand iterating with `argc--` your files are processed in reverse, so you will end up with output like:

```
$ ./bin/searcher test2 test1
test1: A cat ran off

$ ./bin/searcher test1 test2
test2: Apples are red
```

**note:** to process the files in order, just do something like `for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)` instead of `while (argc--)`. Let me know if you have further questions.

Changing to the `for` loop instead of the `while` in `main` and inputting `10` as the number of occurrences to look for, *all* files are processed, e.g.:

```
$ ./bin/searcher test1 test2
test1: A cat ran off
test2: Apples are red
```

Comment: Why is it important to strip new lines?

Comment: Just comment out my `rmlf` and you tell me `:)`  Remember `fgets` *reads and includes the trailing newline* in your `line`. What happens when you print `name` and `line`?

Comment: Is enum really needed? can't I just use something like char size[1000] then sizeof size;

Comment: It's not needed, it is just a convenient way to declare multiple constants. You want to avoid hardcoding *magic numbers* throughout your code, but for purposes of this example, you can nuke it.

Comment: Sure, C takes time to learn. No other language gives you as much control (aside from assembly), and with that comes a lot of responsibility. Don't expect to learn it all in one night. Good luck with your coding.

Comment: Just one, think I comment out rmlf and took at the \n from printf ("%s: %s\n", name, line). And I got some the same result. And thanks for the inspiring quote. As long as there are people like you us beginner will truly find there paths.

Comment: Sure, but removing you get an unexpected `'\n'` in `"%s: %s"` after the first `%s` and before the `:` which is not what it looks like you want.

Comment: Also, I found one small thing problem with the program is you add a large number like 10, it doesn't start reading the next file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115621/discussion-between-david-c-rankin-and-zero).

Comment: Good luck, drop a comment again if you get stuck.

Comment: what was the change you made?

Comment: I changed the `while` to a `for` in `main` and at the bottom of `searcher` I made it `return count == amount ? count : 0;` Which is a *ternary* operator just shorthand for `if (count == amount) return count; else return 0;` Refresh the page -- I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank You, for all the help.

Comment: Yes, that was just to show the *content* of the test **input** files.